# Plotting two series using different colors and marks in Altair

Tags: python, altair

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
| date_column         |   my_point_column |   my_line_column |
|---------------------|-------------------|------------------|
| 2017-12-13 00:00:00 |                 3 |          9.73136 |
| 2018-01-05 00:00:00 |                23 |          6.36568 |
| 2018-01-11 00:00:00 |                 6 |          11.9105 |
| 2018-01-22 00:00:00 |                11 |          10.4328 |
| ...                 |               ... |              ... |
```

I want to plot both series using different marks (points and lines) and they should each be a different color. The color also must be shown in the legend.

I was able to accomplish it with this code, but it's pretty verbose:

```py
# plot_df is the dataframe shown above
chart = alt.Chart(plot_df)

points = chart.transform_fold(
    fold=["my_point_column"],
    as_=["variable", "value"]
).encode(
    x="date_column:T",
    y="my_point_column:Q",
    color="variable:N"
).mark_circle()

line = chart.transform_fold(
    fold=["my_line_column"],
    as_=["variable", "value"]
).encode(
    x="date_column:T",
    y="my_line_column:Q",
    color="variable:N"
).mark_line()

alt.layer(points, line)
```

That code produces this chart:

[image: point and line chart]

That's pretty much the result I'm looking for (outside of customizing the colors, axis titles, etc.). Is there an easier way to do it without having to use transform_fold twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a less verbose solution, you could use one of the charts as the "base" and then overwrite its transform, mark, and y-encoding:

```py
points = alt.Chart(plot_df).mark_circle().transform_fold(
    fold=["my_point_column"]
).encode(
    x="date_column:T",
    y="my_point_column:Q",
    color="key:N")

line = chart.mark_line().transform_fold(
    fold=["my_line_column"]
).encode(
    y="my_line_column:Q")

points + line
```